# Is DataFrameA.columnA the same as DataFrameA.["columnA"] in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm considering changing all my `DataFrameA.columnA` to `DataFrameA["columnA"]` because it looks like the docs use the bracket syntax quite often. It looks like better practice because it offer the opportunity to dynamically pick a column based on a variable instead of hard coded. For example, you could do:

```
columnWanted="columnA"; 
DataFrameA[columnWanted] # Yield ColumnA, GOOD
```

With the other syntax,

```
columnWanted="columnA"; 
DataFrameA.columnWanted # Yields Nothing, BAD. No way of Evaluating Variable.
```

would not work. Because it looks for "`columnWanted`" and there's no way you can put some sort of statement that you want columnWanted to be evaluated for it's value in python.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html

Comment: I don't believe there should be a period between `DataFrameA` and `["columnName"]`.

Comment: @JohnGordon You're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **both** above conventions as long as:

- the column in question exists,
- the column name is a **string literal**, not a variable holding a string.

There is however another limitation to the usage of the *attribute notation*,
namely the column name must be a valid identifier (e.g. it can
not contain any space).

But if you create a **new** column, then the only choice is the *bracket
notation*.

In my opinion, the *attribute notation* is used quite often and
there is no need to change to the *bracket notation* only to use
a single notation only.

Note also that *df.xxx* is more concise than *df['xxx']*, so I prefer
rather the *attribute notation*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it should be `DataFrameA["columnA"]` and not `DataFrameA.["columnA"]`.

Also, here:

```
columnWanted="columnA"; 
DataFrameA.columnWanted # Yields Nothing, BAD. No way of Evaluating Variable.
```

"No way of Evaluating Variable" is not exactly true. You can replace it with

```
columnWanted="columnA"; 
getattr(DataFrameA, columnWanted) # equivalent to DataFrameA.columnA
```

but you should not use this here. It's better practice to use `DataFrameA["columnA"]`.

About the question, both are *exactly* the same. you can see this by running

```
DataFrameA.columnA is DataFrameA["columnA"]
```

The output is `True`

Comment: Didn't know about getattr. Looks like that will come in handy alot